# Bootstrap shows space on left side on mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]
I'm testing this on my iphone 6 and I'm getting a white space on the left of the page. here is my code:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h3 class="col-xs-12">title</h3>
  <div class="row">   
    <ul>
      <li class="col-xs-12 green-box"> 
        <img class="col-xs-12" src="img1.jpg"> text text text 
      </li> 
      <li class="col-xs-12 green-box"> 
        <img class="col-xs-12" src="img2.jpg"> text text text 
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css: I've set the media screen to 320 px;

```
   ul{
      list-style-type:none
     }


   li{
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      background-color: pink;
     }

   .green-box{
     text-justify: inter-word;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 1.1em;
    }
```

Comment: add screenshot of issue you faced in mobile when you view this page in your mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set padding of `ul` 0 and put the `<h3` inside the `<div class="row">`. Have a look

```css
ul{
   padding:0;
   list-style-type:none;
}
li{
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   background-color: green;
}
.green-box{
   text-justify: inter-word;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">  
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="col-xs-12 green-box"> 
        <img class="col-xs-12" src="img1.jpg"> text text text 
      </li> 
      <li class="col-xs-12 green-box"> 
        <img class="col-xs-12" src="img2.jpg"> text text text 
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

set padding: 0; margin: 0; to ul section in css this will fix your problem.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.green-box {
  text-justify: inter-word;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Enjoy :)